# Folder Permissions + Security Concerns

Tags: security, permissions, server, filesystem, linux

I messed up bad guys. I while working on another part of my website I accidentally nuked my WordPress folder permissions. I was able to find/fix some problems and I got my site up and running but some features like posting from the app or working with themes is still broken. Is there a way to reset all of the folder permission to default. I'm really worried that my site is at risk right now with the messed up folder permissions. What are some things to check as far as security to make sure I haven't been compromised.

Comment: Have you tried [Changing file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) on the Codex?

Comment: I did but I cant seem to find where a reset to default option is. I recursively made all of the files and folders as restrictive as possible and increased them a little each time until the site was back up. So my WordPress seems to be serving pages fine but some individual features don't work because the file\folder permissions aren't what they need to be and making everything 777 is clearly out of the option.